# Приложение работает только со второго запуска

Tags: java, android

При первом запуске рисуется экран с кнопкой.
При нажатии на кнопку приложение "падает".
При повторном запуске все Ок.
Ниже логи:

```
Shutting down VM
... W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414ce930)
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.ex.MainActivity.MainMenu(MainActivity.java:449)
at com.ex.MainActivity.onClBtnMenu(MainActivity.java:437)
at com.ex.MainActivity.btnNavigMainActivity(MainActivity.java:201)
at com.ex.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:36)
at com.ex.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:152)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4207)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17372)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 22:06:55.733 1793-11168/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.ex /.MainActivity
```

Код вызова:

```
public void onClBtnMenu(View view) { MainMenu(view); }
private void MainMenu(View v) {
    PopupMenu menu1 = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    menu1.getMenu().add(1,0,0,"Создать");
    subMenu = menu1.getMenu().addSubMenu(2, 1, 0, "Настройки");
    subMenu.add(2,2,0,"Экран");
    subMenu.add(2,3,0,"Синхронизация");
    menu1.getMenu().add(3,4,0,"Выход");
    menu1.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case 0: LM("MENU"); return true;
                case 2: menuSetScr();return true; 
                case 3: menuSync(); return  true;
                case 4: finish();
                default: return false;
                }
                }
            });
    menu1.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu) {  } // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDismiss", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
    menu1.show();
}
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Первая догадка: что-то с меню. Может Вы загружаете в него какие-то данные или что-то того? В любом случае, попробуйте его убрать и посмотреть, что выйдет.

Comment: Почему не приложили строку кода к вопросу где падает?

Comment: Потому, что автор подозревает, что здесь много андроид специалистов, которые знают все строчки кода наизусть.

Comment: Извиняюсь что сразу не приложил код вызова кнопки.